# Why celery not running periodic task at specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Celery not running periodic task at specific time, my celery config with my cron task `send_email_notifications`:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

class Config:
    timezone = 'Europe/Minsk'
    enable_utc = True

    task_always_eager = False
    broker_url = 'amqp://%s:%s@%s:%s//' % (RABBITMQ_USERNAME, RABBITMQ_PASSWORD, RABBITMQ_HOST, RABBITMQ_PORT)
    result_expires = 3600
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
    worker_max_memory_per_child = 250000  # 250MB

    imports = (
        'app.jobs.clients_job',
    )
    task_routes = {
        'app.jobs.clients_job.send_email': {'queue': 'clients'},
        # Periodic tasks
        'app.jobs.clients_job.send_email_notifications': {'queue': 'periodic_api'},
    }

    beat_schedule = {
        'send-email-notifications': {
            'task': 'app.jobs.clients_job.send_email_notifications',
            'schedule': crontab(hour=16, minute=4),
            'args': (),
        },
    }
    worker_hijack_root_logger = False
    accept_content = ['json']


celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object(Config)
```

`app.jobs.clients_job`

```
@celery.task
def send_email_notifications():
    t = datetime.date.today()
    logger.info('started')
    logger.info(t)
```

I'm running celery worker as:

```
`$ celery worker -c 1 -n prtperiodicapi -l INFO -A config.celery_config -B -E -Q periodic_api -s /tmp/api_celerybeat_schedule_periodic`
```

But why task not running at `16:04`?

```
celery == 4.1.1
python 3.5.2
```

server date time

$ date

`Sat May 26 16:02:48 +03 2018`

ALSO:
with empty `crontab()`, periodic task running

UPDATE:
running `celery beat` separately from worker didn't help

```
celery beat v4.1.1 (latentcall) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2018-05-26 16:58:11
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `celery beat` separately and not as part of worker?

Comment: you are setting `enable_utc = True` after `timezone = 'Europe/Minsk'` which resets it to use UTC instead (you were setting it to run at 16:04 localtime, right?)

Comment: I already set this to False, didn't help

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I added new periodic task for ubuntu cron, which run my python script. On celery github.com developers said that it fixed in v4.2.0rc4. I decided not to install `rc` release of celery in my project. You can also wait half of year(maybe more) while they will release stable `v4.2.0`